# Does Dialogflox CX support agent in Arabic language

Tags: dialogflow-cx

Does Dialogflox CX support agent in Arabic language ? The language support documentation mentions Arabic (preview) Text support. I am not sure what preview means here. How to accomplish a english/arabic language chat bot best using dialogueflow CX, please explain.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Dialogflow CX does support Arabic language, you would just need to specify it when you create the agent as show below.

[image: Agent Setup]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can test and use the **ar- Arabic** language in Dialogflow CX.

According to the Product launch stages documentation, at the [Preview stage](https://cloud.google.com/products#section-22), products or features are ready for testing by customers. Preview offerings are often publicly announced, but are not necessarily feature-complete, and no SLAs or technical support commitments are provided for these. Unless stated otherwise by Google, Preview offerings are intended for use in test environments only. The average Preview stage lasts about six months.

If you want to use [multiple languages](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/concept/agent-multilingual) in a Dialogflow CX agent, you can add additional languages in the **Agent settings > Languages** tab. The language you choose when creating an agent is set as the default language. For the complete list, see the [languages reference](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/reference/language) page.

Note that the [requests to the agent](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/concept/agent-multilingual#detect-intent) should contain a language code to match intents of the desired language. If [not specified](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/concept/agent-multilingual#no-lang), the agent's default language is used.